# Fits to optimize large predicted y's

Tags: regression

I'd like to run a regression which places more weight on large predicted y values (y-hats) relative to standard procedures. For my use case, I only really care about the result when the predicted y is large in magnitude. Would appreciate any ideas, thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify the circumstances ... why do you need this (it may help to guide us to better answers)?

Comment: You won't have predicted y values until after you've fitted your model. Are you asking about an iterative approach, or do you mean more weight on large *observed* y values? In addition, what does "more weight" mean? Can you specify a rule you want to use for the weights?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I'm essentially using the predictions to determine the allocation of finite resources.  I can make predictions for my y very cheaply, but only really care about the top <1% of predictions by magnitude because that's where I will allocate researchers for manual intervention.  I want to make sure those cases have as much potential promise as possible.

Comment: I don't really have a set approach in mind (or a good understanding of this field's literature); I'm just brainstorming for potential ideas.  I could weight large y values more before running my regression, but since my work is really targeted towards large predicted y's, I'm wondering if there's anything that targets that more directly.  Thanks for your help!